# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR warning with source id's not beeing found

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

**The Problem:**

Hello, I've been trying to set up Ubuntu(22.04 LTS) as a second system on my main computer(the first OS being Windows). I've followed Tecno Tim's guide on setting up dual boot and the linux os is beeing installed on a 1TB Toshiba hard drive(video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWQMYN12QD0&pp=ygUQZHVhbCBib290IHVidW50dQ%3D%3D) I followed the video in its entirety, but my Ubuntu installation just doesn't install(I ran it for 8 hours),It is stuck in

```
ext4 file system for partition #3 of SCSI2 (0,0,0)(sdb)
```

the warning that it gives is this:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/999) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 999
```

Following that I get Source Id errors:

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:135: Warning: Source ID 16192 was not found when attempting to remove it
    GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

Keep in mind they don't abrupt the installation, It just keeps going for a really long time

**What I've Tried**

- Deleting all partitions on the drive
- Editing grub settings with nano
- Creating partitions myself
- Installing with and without internet
- Disabled fast and secure boot

**Recent update**

As of right now I saw this message:

```
(EE) event5 - Logitech Gaming Keyboard G213: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 28ms, your system is too slow
```

So it is installing 3-rd party driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple, take out a hard drive that has windows installed on it, so that your other drive that you want to install linux on will be first, then install linux, and after that connect the drive. That should solve your issue.